# JList lost in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist

So for some reason when I add JPanels containing a JList to a JTabbedPane (in a JFrame), the JList doesn't show up. All the other stuff like buttons and labels show up, but not the list

JFrame code:

```
public View(Model m, Controller c) {
    model = m;
    controller = c;
    co=getContentPane();
    co.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   

    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    vp = new VragenPanel(model, controller);
    cp = new CategoriePanel(model, controller);
    tabbedPane.add("Vragen", vp);
    tabbedPane.add("Categorie", cp);
    co.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.setSize(400,400);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

JPanel code:

```
public CategoriePanel(Model m, Controller c) {        
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    list = controller.getCategorieList();
    this.add(list, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    ...
    b1 = new JButton(etc)...
}
```

Controller's list code (with defaultlistmodel):

```
    private DefaultListModel dlm=new DefaultListModel();
    private JList lijst=new JList(dlm);
    ...
public JList getCategorieList() {
    dlm.ensureCapacity(100);
    for(int i=0;i<model.getCategoriën().size();i++) {
        dlm.addElement(model.getCategoriën().get(i).getNaam();
    }
    return lijst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `JList` in a `JScrollPane` (`JList` doesn't provide scrolling functionality by itself). Also it is a good idea to set a minimum and preferred size.

Also you can only use `add(list, BorderLayout.NORTH)` if your panel has a `BorderLayout` layout manager (which cannot be told from the code you posted - check on that).

Example:

```
JList list = controller.getCategorieList();
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(list);
Dimension d = new Dimension(100, 100);
sp.setMinimumSize(d);
sp.setPreferredSize(d);
this.add(list, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Sorry, tried to make the code as readable as possible. I am using a borderlayout and have set the minimum size. Will try to add a scrollpane now, thanks in advance.
edit: adding a scrollpane did not work

Comment: list has both coordinates (no row and hint for preffered size)implemented in API, then this answer is wrong

Comment: @mKorbel I suggested to set size of the `JScrollPane` not the `JList`'s.

Comment: again JList has both coordinates implemented in API, that returns to the JScrollPane as PreferredSize, please whats happends if you will follow this suggestion, (but another situation is with JTextPane/JeditorPane)

Comment: Then please post more code about how your `JPanel` and the tabbed pane is added to your frame.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the patience, I've added everything that seemed relevant